# JPA entitymanager working with spring in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using Spring container for entity manager object and faced stale state exception while executing messages.

1. Fetching some data from x table
2. Removing that data from x table
3. Inserting new record in X table.

All above steps are getting executed in same transection.
But during mutithreaded environment I am processing 5000 records but which may have the same condition  which will fetch same records as other thread.

While executing I am getting stale state exception. 
What is correct way to remove entity in multi threaded environment?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the same transaction is shared across all threads? Not sure what your setup is, but commonly transactions contexts are bound to a thread (using threadlocal)... Maybe share the part of the code where you do the transaction dermarcation and forking into seperate treads?

Comment: Hi Frederick.. due to some reason I can't share code. I have created a class where I am getting the entitymanager object using @PersistantContext
Entitymanager em; and its bean creation mapping kept in springcfg.xml. This em object I am getting in dao class using get method. I am using Apache camel for messages routing and its mutithreading feature for creating threads. So if I will receive messages in input then my Apache camel will create separate thread for this. I hope you have got some understanding. If not then I will create a dummy one and  post it.